# Kafka is filling up disk space despite of the retention settings

Tags: apache-kafka

We defined retention time on topics for 15 minutes. It looks like Kafka is deleting the messages as configured however the disk space is not restored. "df -h" output shows 30G for kafka-logs instead of the real size which is supposed to be 1Gb.

{{/usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted }} output shows a bunch of files under kafka-logs that are deleted but they are still consuming space.

Is this a known issue? Is there a setting that I can apply to kafka broker server?

We have Kafka 2.2.0

Comment: Did u use log.cleanup.policy = delete in your broker settings ?

Comment: I suggest doing du on a single partition, not all logs

Comment: What to u mean by du ??

Comment: Kafka-logs folder is located under /part1. When I enter "df -h" I see that the size of /part1 is 29Gb. But when I enter "du -sch /part1/*" as the command to check the folder's size, I see that the size of kafka-logs folder is 1Gb. My issue is similar to this: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316

Comment: Restarting my kafka service resolves the issue and what I see in df output and du output become the same. Obviously, I cannot restart my kafka service on production constantly so I was wondering if anyone ran into this same issue before. My "cleanup.policy" is already set to "delete". Retention time is set for 15 minutes for the topics. Also, I have only 1 broker server.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the docs of Apache Kafka:

```
 retention.ms: This configuration controls the maximum time we will retain a log before we will discard old log segments to free up space. 
   If we are using the "delete" retention policy. This represents an SLA on how soon consumers must read their data. 
   If set to -1, no time limit is applied. 
Type: longDefault: 604800000
Valid Values: [-1,...]
Server Default Property: log.retention.ms
Importance: medium
```

It won't delete the data for the entire system but will only delete the data for that particular consumer group.

In order to delete the data, you have to set the broker level setting:

```
log.cleanup.policy: The default cleanup policy for segments beyond the retention window. A comma-separated list of valid policies. 
Valid policies are: "delete" and "compact"
Type: list
Default: delete
Valid Values: [compact, delete]
Importance: medium
Update Mode: cluster-wide
```

You can also go through the Kafka Documentation on the various Configurations: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration

Comment: What do you mean it won't delete? The default policy tells it to

Comment: It will delete the data for that particular group after the retention.ms ha passed.

Comment: Then why did you bold that it wouldn't?

Comment: I already setup the clean policy to delete. The issue is that unless I restart kafka the disk space is not cleared after deletion.